# When i try to add Jquery cdn link in Chrome Extension MV3 I get Content Security Policy directive error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently I Try to Integrate Jquery Terminal on my chrome extension with manifest version 3, and I've an issue with Content security policy, every time I run the extension, I get this error.

`Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

> I tried this first [Content Security Policy directive issue with MV3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598519/content-security-policy-directive-issue-with-mv3) but it had no answers

Can somebody help me to fix this error using Manifest version 3.

Comment: It's not supported. Put the script into your extension and load it as your other scripts directly without CDN.